# How to right shift bits in c++?

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I have a hex number `0x8F` (10001111 in binary). I want to right shift that value, so the new one would be `0xC7` (11000111). I tried with:

```
unsigned char x = 0x8F;
x=x>>1;
```

but instead of 0xC7 I got 0x47? Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: The expected result '0xC7`is wrong - in other words signed shifts are implementation defined - but you have an unsigned value here

Comment: If you change it to `char` instead of `unsigned char` you'll get the behavior that you expect. On unsigned, the sign bit is always 0. On signed, you'll shift in the high order bit, so negative numbers fill with 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @Charlie: As long as `char` is signed, and shifting a signed value gives sign-extension. Neither of these are guaranteed in C++.

Comment: @MikeSeymour fair point, but all of the answers are giving rotate right code. I suppose we need a better example, like the expected result of 10000010 >> 1. A shift with sign extension would give 11000001 and a rotate would give 01000001.

Comment: @spunky031 Just to be clear, do you want *signed shift right* (rightmost bit lost, leftmost bit duplicated on the left), or do you want *bit rotation right* (no bits lost, as rightmost bit moves to the leftmost position)? Both fit your example data...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right shift on an unsigned quantity will make new **zeros** to enter, not ones.

Note that right shift is not a right **rotation**. To do that you need

```
x = (x >> 1) | (x << 7)
```

Answer (score 8):

That's because what you want is a "rotate right", not "shift right". So you need to adjust for the lowest bit "falling off":

```
 x = ((x & 1) << CHAR_BITS-1) | (x >> 1);
```

should do the trick.

[And at least some compilers will detect this particular set of operations and convert to the corresponding `ror` or `rol` instruction]

Answer (score 2):

Right shifting or left shifting will fill with `0`s respectively on the left or on the right of the byte. After shifting, you need to `OR` with the proper value in order to get what you expect.

```
x = (x >> 1); /* this is now 01000111 */
x = x | ( 0x80 ); /* now we get what we want */
```

Here I'm `OR`ing with the byte `10000000` which is `0x80` resulting in `0xC7`.

Making it more concise, it becomes:

```
x = (x >> 1) | (unsigned char)0x80;
```